# A way to remove selected LineShape shadow effect?

Tags: .net, vb.net, drawing, powerpacks

Is there a way to remove the LineShape shadow effect when selecting the lineShape?

[alt text http://lh4.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/S6kq2KQ-zdI/AAAAAAAADIg/tUy74j-EpQc/s800/capture4.png](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/S6kq2KQ-zdI/AAAAAAAADIg/tUy74j-EpQc/s800/capture4.png)

I tried

```
  Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
    Dim oldmode As SmoothingMode = g.SmoothingMode
    g.DrawLine(_Pen, X1, Y1, X2, Y2)
    g.SmoothingMode = oldmode
  End Sub
```

but finally, this have some back effects on invalidation: when moving (in a panel) the line leave traces - does not invalidate properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the SelectionColor to Transparent.